# sqllite3 install on node and macos give error

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have a sqllite database (.db) file which I want to connect to using node.  I assume I need to use the package `sqlite3`.  However when I try to install this I get the following error

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@4.2.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.2.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

My node version is 14.3.0.  From what I checked I need to use sqlite3 to connect to the .db file.  Is there some other package I can use or does anyone know how to fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue on **Ubuntu 20.04**, **node version 14.5.0** until when i came across  [sqlite3 npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3). Simply execute the following commands if you are on Ubuntu 20.04:

1. sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
2. Navigate to your project directory and then execute **npm i sqlite3**